# Booking an East London Tennis Court

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium

## Description

I'm not sure if it Covid-19 but lately it is impossible to book a tennis court in my area on time. It's always full or maybe just don't check enough :)

To beat the queue and get notified earlier, I started making a scraper to ensure I can book a court on time.

But because of iframe hell and the lack (to my knowledge) of an API it was impossible to do it the easy way, hence I used selenium. I coded this today and it works pretty well, although it's already become a bit of a mess.

## Todo

Dynamically detecting the hours available and starting time of the day, so I don't have to supply those values anymore, because my guess is they will change (depending on the time it will get dark etc.)

You can still flame me for it, but I just haven't found a good way to do it yet, now I just supply them in the `COURTS` dictionary

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# At what minimal time I am willing/able to book
WEEKEND_TIME = 10
WEEK_TIME = 18

COURTS = {
    # Some courts have different hours available and the hour at which you can start can differ
    # Thus it is key -> name with values -> url, hours available, time diff start
    "Bethnal Green Gardens" : ["https://www.towerhamletstennis.org.uk/bethnal-green-gardens-court-bo", 14, 0],
    "St Johns Park"         : ["https://www.towerhamletstennis.org.uk/st-johns-park-court-boo", 14, 1],
    "Poplar Rec"            : ["https://www.towerhamletstennis.org.uk/poplar-rec-court-bookin", 12, 0],
    "King Edward's Park"    : ["https://www.towerhamletstennis.org.uk/kemp-court-bookin", 12, 0],
    "Victoria Park"         : ["https://www.towerhamletstennis.org.uk/victoria-park-court-book", 12, 0],
}

def get_week_schedule(driver, time_length, time_start, first_week=True):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="cal_time cal_time_time"]')
    sched = [e.text for e in elem.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="inc"]')]
    times = sched[time_start:17]
    active = sched[17:]

    # When first week we only want from x till sunday and second week monday till x
    days = ["Sunday", "Saturday", "Friday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Monday"]
    active_days = days[:len(active) // time_length][::-1] if first_week \
             else days[::-1][:len(active) // time_length]
    
    week_schedule = {}
    for i, active_day in enumerate(active_days):
        week_schedule[active_day] = {
            int(times[j].split(":")[0]) : active[i * time_length + j]
            for j in range(time_length)
        }
    return week_schedule

def get_court_schedule(driver, data):
    url, time_length, time_start = data
    driver.get(url)
    
    # Yo dawg, I heard you like iframes so I put an iframe in your iframe...
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe")))    
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

    court_schedule = {}
    court_schedule["this"] = get_week_schedule(driver, time_length, time_start)

    # Next week is second element
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]/span")
    elem[1].click()
    # TODO Fix time.sleep...  but same page so how can we wait?
    time.sleep(5)
    court_schedule["next"] = get_week_schedule(driver, time_length, time_start, first_week=False)

    return court_schedule

def get_schedule():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    court_schedules = {
        court_name : get_court_schedule(driver, url)
        for court_name, url in COURTS.items()
    }

    driver.quit()
    return court_schedules

def get_available_dates(schedule):
    for court_name, court_schedule in schedule.items():
        for week, week_schedule in court_schedule.items():
            for day, day_schedule in week_schedule.items():
                earliest_time = WEEKEND_TIME if day in ("Saturday", "Sunday") else WEEK_TIME
                for hour, available in day_schedule.items():
                    if hour >= earliest_time and available not in ("Full", " "):
                        print(f"Can book at court {court_name} {week} week on {day} at {hour} for price {available}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    schedule = get_schedule()
    get_available_dates(schedule)
```

## Example output

```
./tennis.py
Can book at court Poplar Rec next week on Saturday at 10 for price £6
Can book at court Poplar Rec next week on Saturday at 11 for price £6
Can book at court King Edward's Park this week on Saturday at 18 for price £6
Can book at court King Edward's Park next week on Friday at 18 for price £6
Can book at court King Edward's Park next week on Saturday at 10 for price £6
Can book at court King Edward's Park next week on Saturday at 11 for price £6
```

Comment: Hey. Are the various PEP 8 violations intentional?

Comment: I am aware of them, yes. :)

Comment: Ah, I though so. :) Might be worth mentioning that in the post.

Comment: The widget seems driven by bookingbug. 
Api here: https://uk.bookingbug.com/apidocs/v1/index.html
Might work...

Answer (score 1):

### Managing `driver`

Any time a resource needs to be cleaned up at the end of life, such as `object.close()`, a context manager can be really nice to have. This way if you hit an exception the object still gets cleaned up, which might not be the case otherwise.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def get_driver():
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        yield driver
    finally:
        driver.quit()


def get_schedule():
    with get_driver() as driver:
        court_schedules = {
            court_name : get_court_schedule(driver, url)
            for court_name, url in COURTS.items()
        }

    return court_schedules
```

### `Courts` global var

I think this could be restructured by eliminating the common base url and just using the extension. The values on the dictionary could be `namedtuple`s for readability. A list is unnecessary, you don't need the mutability here:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

CourtInfo = namedtuple('CourtInfo', ['uri', 'time_length', 'time_start'])

BASE_URL = 'https://www.towerhamletstennis.org.uk'

COURTS = {
    # Some courts have different hours available and the hour at which you can start can differ
    # Thus it is key -> name with values -> url, hours available, time diff start
    "Bethnal Green Gardens": CourtInfo("bethnal-green-gardens-court-bo", 14, 0),
    "St Johns Park": CourtInfo("st-johns-park-court-boo", 14, 1),
    "Poplar Rec": CourtInfo("poplar-rec-court-bookin", 12, 0),
    "King Edward's Park": CourtInfo("kemp-court-bookin", 12, 0),
    "Victoria Park": CourtInfo("victoria-park-court-book", 12, 0),
}
```

As a stylistic note, you don't need the extra spaces surrounding the colons in your dictionaries.

### `get_court_schedule` args

The arguments here are implicitly an iterable, since they get unpacked in the first line of the function. Second, `data` is not a great variable name. Paired with a lack of type hints or docstrings, a user of this code would need to read the actual function to see what's going on. Let's expand on the `namedtuple` that we used earlier:

```py
# I don't know what an actual signature for a webdriver would be
# so I'm making one up for now
def get_court_schedule(
    driver: 'WebDriver', 
    uri: str, 
    time_length: int, 
    time_start: int
) -> dict:
    # now you don't need to unpack these
    # and can format the url together
    driver.get(f"{BASE_URL}/{uri}")
    ...
```

And to call the function:

```py
court_schedules = {
    court_name : get_court_schedule(driver, *info)
    for court_name, info in COURTS.items()
}
```

### Long Lines

Any line that's continued by a `\` can instead use parentheses:

```py
# instead of this
active_days = days[:len(active) // time_length][::-1] if first_week \
     else days[::-1][:len(active) // time_length]

# do this
active_days = (
    days[:len(active) // time_length][::-1]
    if first_week else
    days[::-1][:len(active) // time_length]
)
```

This works for most other things as well:

```py
# go from this
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe")))

# to this
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//iframe"))
)


# you can break up dotted expressions even further
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

(
    driver
    .switch_to
    .frame(
        driver
        .find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
    )
)
```

This last example is a bit extreme, but illustrates the point.

You should certainly be using it for function calls that start to be long:

```py
# This
court_schedule["next"] = get_week_schedule(driver, time_length, time_start, first_week=False)

# becomes this
court_schedule["next"] = get_week_schedule(
    driver, 
    time_length, 
    time_start, 
    first_week=False
)
```

### `get_available_dates`

I don't love how wide this gets, even though you can't completely avoid it. I'd make a generator out of this and put the print statement in a new function:

```py
def get_available_dates(schedule):
    for court_name, court_schedule in schedule.items():
        for week, week_schedule in court_schedule.items():
            for day, day_schedule in week_schedule.items():
                for hour, available in day_schedule.items():
                    if available in ('Full', ' '):
                        continue
                    yield (
                        court_name, 
                        week, 
                        day, 
                        hour, 
                        available
                    )


# Let's use a main function here
def main():
    schedule = get_schedule()

    # Now unpack this later
    dates = get_available_dates(schedule)
    
    for court_name, week, day, hour, available in dates:
        # I've moved this statement here and broken it
        # up to be a bit easier to read
        if day in ('Saturday', 'Sunday'):
            earliest_time = WEEKEND_TIME
        else:
            earliest_time = WEEK_TIME
    
        # now test for this calculated value
        if not hour >= earliest_time:
            continue
    
        # no else statement needed here
        print(
            f"Can book at court {court_name} {week} "
            f"week on {day} at {hour} for price {available}"
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```